# Pass updated Model features to logistic regression and get predicted score on test set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels, coefficients

I am new to statistic modelling so please forgive if I am mistaken about this.

I am currently working on a function in python which will predict accuracy score for logistics regression model on the test data set. User will have the flexibility to supply model parameters/coefficients (other than the ones generated by training model-part of the requirement). I have a functional code which updates the coefficients but accuracy or prediction on test data set stays the same no matter how different model parameters I supply. My understanding is that the score on test set should change if I change model coefficients?

I am using statsmodel library to make things easier for me and following this [link](https://github.com/Mashimo/datascience/blob/master/01-Regression/LogisticRegressionSM.ipynb). Can someone please help me understand what am I missing ? Below is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv("E:\\Dev\\testing\\rawdata.txt", header=None, 
               names=['Exam1', 'Exam2', 'Admitted'])
X = data.copy() # ou training data
y = X.Admitted.copy() # copy “y” column values out
X.drop(['Admitted'], axis=1, inplace=True) # then, drop y column
# manually add the intercept
X['intercept'] = 1.0  # so we don't need to use sm.add_constant every time
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
model = sm.Logit(y_train, X_train)
result = model.fit()
print("old parameters :\n" + str(list(result.params)))
#New parameters supplied
mdict = { 'Exam1':10000000.2234, 'Exam2':1.1233423, 'intercept':2313.423 }
result.params = mdict
print("New parameters: \n"+str(result.params))

def logitPredict(modelParams, X, threshold):  
     probabilities = modelParams.predict(X)
    return [1 if x >= threshold else 0 for x in probabilities]

predictions = logitPredict(result, X_test, .5)
accuracy = np.mean(predictions == y_test)
#accuracy always remains same as train model
print ('accuracy = {0}%'.format(accuracy*100)  )
#test sample
myExams = pd.DataFrame({'Exam1': [40.], 'Exam2': [78.], 'intercept': [1.]})
myExams
print ('Your probability = {0}%'.format(result.predict(myExams)[0]*100))
```

Comment: How are you passing different parameters to your function which calculates accuracy? Its not present here?

Comment: I declared the dictionary mdict and replaced the parameters as result.params = mdict in above code. I used the same result object of model with updated model to predict new output. Sadly, I dont understand why the model prediction is returning same values

Comment: from further debugging, it looks like the params attribute is not used in predict function. I had a look at other attributes of model object("result" in this case) like co_variates(). I will take a look at attribute that actually is used in calculating the accuracy. There are a lot of them so It may be a while before I post the solution.